# why localhost not working for node js api

Tags: node.js, api, mongoose

I am creating api in nodejs and mongodb but the url is not working here are the files:

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const url = 'mongodb://localhost/AlienDBex'

const app = express()

mongoose.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser:true})
const con = mongoose.connection

con.on('open', () => {
    console.log('connected...')
})

app.use(express.json())

const alienRouter = require('./routes/aliens')
app.use('/aliens',alienRouter)

app.listen(9000, () => {
    console.log('Server started')
})



  aliens.js

const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Alien = require('../models/alien')


router.get('/', async(req,res) => {
    try{
        //    const aliens = await Alien.find()
           res.json('aliens')
    }catch(err){
        res.send('Error ' + err)
    }
})
module.exports = router



 alien.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const alienSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    tech: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    sub: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Alien',alienSchema)
```

Url:https://localhost:9000/aliens is not working.
I have installed node js properly but localhost is not working for the above url.
please help me out i have intalled all the packages but it is not working.

Comment: What is the output on your console?

Comment: there is nothing in the console except the    [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
(node:6136) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the
new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Server started
connected...

Answer (score 0):

Because the localhost url also have a port number.
Now, if you  installed mongodb correctly the most probable url must look like.

`const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/yourCollectionName"`

Comment: it could not solve the issue.please provide any other solution
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

why are you using https ? use http only for localhost because you don't have ssl setup locally
`http://localhost:9000`